# Unix history not working

Tags: unix, history, ksh

I'm using `ksh` on unix and connect through `putty`.

My `.sh_history` stores all history commands but when I press up arrow nothing comes, please help me.

Comment: Do your arrow keys work in any other programs?

Comment: history is working, but you key mappings get screwed up, don't know ksh to help you with a proper answer

Comment: my arrow keys are working fine. i guess they are not mapped properly. also i don have .kshrc file

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me, when I'd press any arrow key some strange characters would come when i connect to a remote machine using putty. I don't know why it happened but the remedy is, you have to type the following in the command line.

$ stty -erase backspace enter

i dont remember what is the prompt of ksh($ or #)

EDIT:
i found this link,hope this helps:

[Make Arrow and delete keys work in Korn shell Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-korn-shell-command-line/2539905#2539905)

Comment: when i try stty -erase backspace enter, it says erase not a valid option for stty

Comment: try
stty erase bskp enter

Comment: no luck dude. but it made my backspace key not wrking

Comment: wait lemme try now... it's been a while so, a few combinations coming to my mind... i'll get back to you

Comment: stty erase ctrl+v bksp enter....
ctrl+v then backspace will show ^H on the terminal
then press enter

Comment: aditya no luck on these commands too. when i checked my home dir i have only couple of files like .profile and .sh_history and one more. but tere is no .kshrc or .chsrc. will this give u any idea. its a unix machine and am granted access just now

Answer (score 0):

set -o emacs should do the trick. [The default config doesn't set the editing mode](http://uw713doc.sco.com/en/SHL_custom/Command_history.html).

Comment: i tried set -o emacs but no luck its still the same. nothing comes when i press up arrow

Comment: HISTFILE and HISTSIZE are set in the shell? and it's keeping the contents as you type? You've checked that the Terminal->Keyboard settings for the function keys are 'ESC[n~' and what is the ksh version?

Comment: my version is M-11/16/88f. HISTFILE and HISTSIZE are set. HISTSIZE is 1024 and HISTFILE is /home/user/.sh_history. also the recalling of commands using escape and k is wrking. i would like to change it to up arrow like c shell. kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the up arrow is a function of bash rather than history (ie: if you have history enabled in ksh or csh it won't work..)

You can either type "bash" once you connect or change the default shell of that user to /bin/bash